# Trying to implement closure on event handler? Error: undefined

Tags: javascript, event-handling, closures, dom-events

I have trying to get the values out of a form when the register button is clicked.

- `setupFormUI()` and the relevant form fields are saved in variables
- `$($rego_form).on("submit", getRegistrationFormValue);` is called - a handler should be able to have access to `setupFormUI()` variables (closure) but it seems to not do anything

> **ISSUE**: `getRegistrationFormValue` doesn't log anything. I can make it work if I pass arguments to the function... **but I want to use
>   closure**

```
setupFormUI();


function setupFormUI() {
    var $name = $("#name");
    var $age = $("#age");
    var $department = $("#department");
    var $position = $("#position");
    var $rego_form = $("#rego-form");

    $($rego_form).on("submit", getRegistrationFormValue);

} 
function getRegistrationFormValue() {
    // alert("asdasd");
    var name = $name.val();
    var age = $age.val();
    var department = $department.val();
    var position = $position.val();

    console.log("----->", name, age, position, department);
}
```

**html**

```
<form id="rego-form">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Company" value="Creative Code Inc.">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" value="michael">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Age</label>
                <input id="age" class="form-control" placeholder="age">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Department Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="department" class="form-control" placeholder="department" value="Marketing">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Position</label>
                <input type="text" id="position" class="form-control" placeholder="position" value="social media manager">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="rego-user-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Register</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just define `getRegistrationFormValue` inside `setupFormUI`?

Comment: The problem having it inside the event handler is the values go away soon as the event is "handled"

Comment: Feel free to assign to outside variables if you want them to be persistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the variables to be in scope, you can use an anonymous closure as a callback to achieve this.

```
setupFormUI();


function setupFormUI() {
    var $name = $("#name");
    var $age = $("#age");
    var $department = $("#department");
    var $position = $("#position");
    var $rego_form = $("#rego-form");

    $rego_form.on("submit", function(){
      var name = $name.val();
      var age = $age.val();
      var department = $department.val();
      var position = $position.val();

     console.log("----->", name, age, position, department); 
   });   

}
```

Comment: The problem having it inside the event handler is the values go away soon as the event is "handled"

Comment: What do you want to do with the values? That would give me a better idea of what direction to point you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer — give the "handler" a meaningful context of `this` with [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), or maybe just use the ES6 `class`.

```js
setupFormUI();

function setupFormUI() {
  var args = {
    $name: $("#name"),
    $age: $("#age"),
    $department: $("#department"),
    $position: $("#position"),
    $rego_form: $("#rego-form")
  }

  args.$rego_form.submit(getRegistrationFormValue.bind(args));

}

function getRegistrationFormValue(e) {
  var name = this.$name.val();
  var age = this.$age.val();
  var department = this.$department.val();
  var position = this.$position.val();

  console.log("----->", name, age, position, department);

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="rego-form" action="#">
  <input id="name" value="John Doe" />
  <input id="age" value="37" />
  <input id="department" value="Some dept" />
  <input id="position" value="Debt collector" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no closure, if the variable in `setupFormUI` is referenced, it is a closure.

`getRegistrationFormValue` is just a variable whose function is passed directly to the event trigger (and is asynchronous), **note that it is not executed in `setupFormUI`, nor is it defined in `setupFormUI`**, When it is executed, it has nothing to do with `setupFormUI`.

Mike Zinn's answer **defines an anonymous function in `setupFormUI`, which in turn refers to the variable in `setupFormUI`**, which is a closure.